# How to Print an iFrame with base64 data

Tags: iframe, printing

This is my Code to print Iframe

```
      <Iframe src="data:application/pdf;base64,JVBERi0x...."></Iframe>
       //javascript Code
      var frame = document.getElementById('printFrame');
        if (!frame) {
            alert("Error: Can't find printing frame.");
            return;
        }
        frame = frame.contentWindow;
        frame.focus();
        frame.print();
```

Error Message:

> The frame requesting access has a protocol of "http", the frame being accessed has a protocol of "data". Protocols must match